# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

As part of Project requirements. I have upgraded the Java version to 1.8 and JBOSS 7.2. while deploying to the application to server i am getting below error. Could you please help me to resolve the issue.

```
2021-05-10 01:40:20,250 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "*******.war" (runtime-name: "*******.war")
2021-05-10 01:40:21,426 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for GTSDBManager
2021-05-10 01:40:21,519 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."*******.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."*******.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "*******.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:151)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:73)
    ... 10 more

2021-05-10 01:40:21,520 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 4) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ({"deployment" => "*******.war"}) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"*******.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"*******.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"}}
2021-05-10 01:40:21,520 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 4) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "*******.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"*******.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"*******.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"}}
2021-05-10 01:40:21,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment *******.war (runtime-name: *******.war) in 31ms
```

Comment: Are you bundling Hibernate in your deployment?

Comment: Yes James. We are using all Hibernate features into the application

Comment: Try not including Hibernate in your deployment. JBoss EAP already includes Hibernate as it's JPA implementation.